# While loop crashing browser when requesting data from API with javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got an API which serves a random item from a list when a button is clicked on a web page. I'm trying to create a loop that fetches a new random item every two seconds and then updates the field on the page. Below is my code, when i click button two it crashes the browser even though i've used a 2 second pause.

Obviously the loop is crashing it but i don't know how to fix it. I thought the pause would do the trick but it's not.

Thanks in advance.

```
"use strict";

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

// generate random word

document.querySelector(".button-one").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_random/");
  request.send();

  request.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    // load random into text field.
    let returnedRandom = this.responseText;
    document.querySelector(".display-box-one").textContent = returnedRandom;
  });
});

// loop through and keep generating random words

document.querySelector(".button-two").addEventListener("click", function () {
  let active = true;
  do {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_random/");
    request.send();

    request.addEventListener("load", function () {
      let returnedRandom = this.responseText;
      document.querySelector(".display-box-one").textContent = returnedRandom;
      console.log(returnedRandom);
    });

    sleep(2000);
  } while (active);
});
```

Comment: why not using `setInterval()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: Are you going to support old browsers or what? The modern approach would use fetch and async/await. And would be much easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

promise based approach

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), milliseconds)
}
```

*changes:*

1. now, here you need to make the `click` event-handler function as `async function` to handle the promise-based behavior of the sleep function.
2. add `await` keyword to sleep function

```
document.querySelector(".button-two").addEventListener("click", async function () {
  let active = true;
  do {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_random/");
    request.send();

    request.addEventListener("load", function () {
      let returnedRandom = this.responseText;
      document.querySelector(".display-box-one").textContent = returnedRandom;
      console.log(returnedRandom);
    });

    // add await keyword.
    await sleep(2000);
  } while (active);
});
```

here is the mdn documantion about async / await:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I've never heard of promise before. Thanks, I've looked into it now and this way is better.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer callbacks to be better understood than Promise.

```
"use strict";

function sleep(milliseconds, foo_then) {
  setTimeout(foo_then, milliseconds)
}

// generate random word

document.querySelector(".button-one").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_random/");
  request.send();

  request.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    // load random into text field.
    let returnedRandom = this.responseText;
    document.querySelector(".display-box-one").textContent = returnedRandom;
  });
});

let active = false;

// loop through and keep generating random words
function my_click() {

  if (!active) {
    return;
  }

  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_random/");
  request.send();

  request.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let returnedRandom = this.responseText;
    document.querySelector(".display-box-one").textContent = returnedRandom;
    console.log(returnedRandom);
  });


  // maybe better place this in the xhr load event
  sleep(2000, my_click);
}

document.querySelector(".button-two").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  active = true;
  my_click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Wiktor mentions in the comments [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) with [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) would be a more modern and easier to understand approach.

Since I don't have access to your API I mocked one.

For your API in `getData` replace

```
const data = await mockApi();
```

with

```
const response = await fetch(endpoint);
const data = await response.text();
```

assuming your response is text and not JSON (in which case you would use `.json()` instead).

```js
// Cache your elements
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const random = document.querySelector('.random');

// Add an event listener to the button that calls
// `getData` when it is clicked
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.disabled = true;
  getData();
});

// Returns a random number
function rnd() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
}

// Mock API which returns a random number
// after one second
function mockApi() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(rnd()), 1000);
  });
}

// `await` the data (number) from the mock API
// and set your cached element's text content
// as that number. Finally call `getData` again
// after two seconds
async function getData() {
  const data = await mockApi();
  random.textContent = data;
  setTimeout(getData, 2000);
}
```

```css
button { border-radius: 5px; }
button:not(:disabled):hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: lightgreen; }
.random { margin-top: 1em; color: blue; }
```

```html
<button>Repeat</button>
<div class="random"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy... I'll try rewriting it with a modern approach.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by *crashing the browser* you actually mean the browser tab freezes and becomes unresponsive!?

Looking at your `sleep()` function this is to be expected because in that function your code does not actually sleep but performs [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), i.e., it just executes a loop until the specified time passed. But this will just waste and use up all available CPU.

Since the `sleep()` function is called from another infinite loop this prevents the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) from processing any other events or callbacks. So your `load` event listener to display the returned result will never be executed.

To get a better understanding and find a more suitable solution you should read up on async programming in javascript, especially using [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Instead of your own `sleep()` function you should use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

The other answers here provide some good examples of proper solutions for your example using async callbacks and `Promises`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation acran. Good to know. I've now read up on Promises.